# displaying stored data in textarea

Tags: jquery, html, ruby, yaml

I am storing data in a YAML file which is received from a textarea (html page) on a particular date.

In YAML it is storing in this format:

`09_09_2015: ! "hello this is sireesha\n   1.some information \n2.some information"`

When I get this data from YAML and display it in a textarea, it is displaying as:

`"hello this is sireesha\n   1.some information \n2.some information"`

How can I overcome this and display this text as

```
hello this is sireesha
   1.some information
   2.some information
```

in the textarea?

Comment: if it is javascript replace `\\n` with `\r\n`. like this: `TextareaElement.value = TextareaElement.value.replace("\\n", "\r\n");` . I dont know ruby

Comment: what have you tried,which language are you using to render it to text area?

Comment: @suresh I dont think `<br>` would work within a textarea . would it?

Comment: @TechJS Sorry.. Yeah it dont work ..i need some thing like this &#10; .

Comment: In jquery before painting data, Store the data into one variable and use variable.replace("\n","");

Answer (score 0):

use jquery `.text()` , [Working demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/en6f2mq8/),'toTest' is the id of your text area.

```
$("#toTest").val($("<div/>").html("hello this is sireesha \n 1.some information \n2.some information").text());
```