# how to display stored data(from database) in textarea which is in json format

Tags: jquery, html, ruby, json, postgresql

This solution does not work [displaying stored data in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32471160/displaying-stored-data-in-textarea?answertab=active#tab-top).. can u please check my code and let me know what is wrong?

In Ruby, I am having a handler which will get the encrypted data from database and decoding and sending to jquery function which will display the text from database on the textarea on change of drop down table

```
Ruby code:
    get '/show_previousdata' do
        projectName=params[:name]
        record=Array.new
        description=Array.new
        record=Project.filter(:project_name=>projectName).first
        project_id=record[:projects_id]
        description=Highlight.filter(:projects_id=>project_id).first
        if description==nil
           highlight="no data"
        else
           highlight=Zlib::Inflate.inflate(description[:description]) 
        end 
        highlight.to_json
   end
Jquery code:
   $("#project_list").change(function () {
     var index = $(this).find("option:selected").index();
     var text_val = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
     if(index!=0)
     {
        $.get('/show_previousdata',
        {
            name:text_val
        },
        function(data,status){
            $("#text_area").val($("<div/>").html(data).text());    
        });
        $('#highlights_textarea').show();
     }
     else
     {
        $('#highlights_textarea').hide();
     }
}); 
haml code:
 %textarea{:id => "text_area",:cols => "20", :rows => "20",:class => "textarea1"}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the problem your facing ?

Comment: i am not able to display text (from databse)in a proper format which i mentioned in that link...(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32471160/displaying-stored-data-in-textarea?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: when u do a console.log(data) whats the value you are getting ?

Comment: i getting data in this format "hello this is sireesha\n   1.some information \n2.some information"

Comment: can u try the answer below and see

Comment: i tried using that ..but it is not working in my code ..if i use a variable in javascript to store some data in string format..then if i try to display that then it is working fine ...but my data is coming from ruby code in json format .. .. may be because of that it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this and see

```
$("#toTest").val($("<div/>").html("hello this is sireesha \r\n 1. hello \r\n 2. hello2 ").text());
```

The fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/en6f2mq8/3/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @silwar Gotcha ! Will do that

Comment: i tried using that ..but it is not working in my code ..if i use a variable in javascript to store some data in string format..then if i try to display that then it is working fine ...but my data is coming from ruby code in json format .. .. may be because of that it is not working

Comment: then do JSON.stringify(data) and try

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify